# How to manage the Blank White screen while loading FBGraph login Webview in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I am implementing `FBgraph` API after log in screen it shows white screen with label "`Success`", at that time i need `Activity indicator` . please give me solution.

Answer (score 2):

Goto FBGraph.m and 
Add `ActivityIndicator` in this following Method

```
-authenticateUserWithCallbackObject
```

And `Remove ActivityIndicator` in following Method

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView
{
     // Remove Indicator here
}
```